# Understanding the Definition of Essentially Surjective

Tags: category-theory

According to this [definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+surjective+functor) of an **essentially surjective functor**:

> [A functor] $F: C \rightarrow D$ is **essentially surjective** if for every object $y$ of $D$, there exists an object $x$ of $C$ and an isomorphism $F(x) \cong y$ in $D$.

**Question:** What is here meant by the $F(x) \cong y$? Does it mean that there exists an arrow $h$ in $D$ s.t. $h: F(x) \rightarrow y$ is invertible in $D$ (i.e., that $h$ is an isomorphism in $D$)?

Comment: It means $F(x)$ and $y$ are isomorphic, yes.

Comment: So my articulation using $h$ above is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}{}$